# How to get ubuntu to associate Nvidia graphics with hdmi port?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, asus, hdmi

I am relatively new to ubuntu and I am having problems with my hdmi port.

My laptop is an Asus N56VM with hybrid graphics: Intel HD 4000 (intergrated) and Nvidia GeForce GT 630M 2gb.

I have a multiple-monitor setup, one plugged into the hmdi port, one in the vga and the laptop display. When running ubuntu the one plugged into the hdmi occasionally works and when it does the display doesn't run smoothly and is very glitchy. (the vga and laptop display work fine)

When running windows 7 the Nvidia graphics card runs the monitor plugged into the hdmi, where the intel runs the laptop display and the vga monitor. (everything works fine on windows 7)

I believe that the problem is due to the lack of the lack of a driver or software that associates the hdmi port with the Nvidia graphics card. I have looked into it and tried installing a few drivers but this has only caused more problems and has not fixed the issue.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?